# How do I convert this Nicomachus's Triangle to one with edges?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I want to put edges on this [Nicomachus's Triangle](http://oeis.org/A036561)

```
r = 7;
t = Table[2^(n - k) 3^k, {n, 0, r}, {k, 0, n}];
ColumnForm[t, Center]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Using Mr. Wizard's method

```
triangleForm[t : {_List ..} /; Depth@t == 3] :=
 Show[Graphics[{
    Red,
    (Line /@ Join[#, Riffle @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]]) &@
      Table[{(1 - i + 2 j - r)/2, i - r - 1}, {i, 0, r}, {j, i, r}],
    MapIndexed[Text[Panel[#, FrameMargins -> 0], {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &,     t, {2}]
   }],
  TextStyle -> FontSize -> 18
 ]

triangleForm[t]
```

[image: NicomachusTriangle]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150259/question-about-the-collatz-conjecture-nicomachuss-triangle-and-more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
triangleForm[t : {_List ..} /; Depth@t == 3] :=
 Show[Graphics[{
    MapIndexed[Text[#, {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &, t, {2}],
    Red,
    Line[{{1/2, -1}, {1 - #/2, -#}, {#/2, -#}, {1/2, -1}}] & @ Length[t]
   }],
  TextStyle -> FontSize -> 18]

triangleForm[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or probably more like:

```
triangleForm[t : {_List ..} /; Depth@t == 3] :=
 Show[Graphics[{
    MapIndexed[Text[#, {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &, t, {2}],
    Red,
    Line[{{1/2, 0}, {-#/2, -# - 1/2}, {1 + #/2, -# - 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}] & @ Length[t]
   }],
  TextStyle -> FontSize -> 18]

triangleForm[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

With automatic image size:

```
r = 9;
t = Table[2^(n - k) 3^k, {n, 0, r}, {k, 0, n}];

triangleForm[t : {_List ..} /; Depth@t == 3] :=
 Show[Graphics[{
    MapIndexed[Text[#, {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &, t, {2}],
    Red,
    Line[{{1/2, 0}, {-#/2, -# - 1/2}, {1 + #/2, -# - 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}] & @ Length[t]
   }],
  TextStyle -> FontSize -> 16,
  ImageSize -> (Length@t + 1) * First@Rasterize[Style[t[[-1, -1]], 16], "RasterSize"]
 ]

triangleForm[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another variation following a comment below:

```
r = 8;
t = Table[2^(n - k) 3^k, {n, 0, r}, {k, 0, n}];

triangleForm[t : {_List ..} /; Depth@t == 3] :=
 Show[Graphics[{
    Red,
    (Line /@ Join[#, Riffle @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]]) &@
      Table[{(1 - i + 2 j - r)/2, i - r - 1}, {i, 0, r}, {j, i, r}],
    MapIndexed[Text[Panel[#, FrameMargins -> 0], {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &, t, {2}]
   }],
  TextStyle -> FontSize -> 18
 ]

triangleForm[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @belisarius are you making the graphic large enough for all the numbers?

Comment: Can you pre-calculate the image size? :D

Comment: @belisarius I suppose so; let me try

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, like the first one, but with all the inner triangles shown also.

Comment: @Fred okay, give me a minute. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, actually I think it would be less cluttered if no edges were shown at all.  Sorry to put you to all that work.

Comment: @Fred Are you sure? :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the last one is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Fred cool. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative way to create the latter picture in Mr.Wizard's answer using `Graph`:

```
elem[n_, k_] := 2^(n - k) 3^k

Block[{e, r},
 r = 7;
 vertices = Flatten[Table[e[n, k], {n, 0, r}, {k, 0, n}]];
 edges = Flatten[{
     Table[e[n, k] \[UndirectedEdge] e[n + 1, k], {n, 0, r - 1}, {k, 0, n}],
     Table[e[n, k] \[UndirectedEdge] e[n + 1, k + 1], {n, 0, r - 1}, {k, 0, n}],
     Table[e[n, k] \[UndirectedEdge] e[n, k + 1], {n, 1, r}, {k, 0, n - 1}]}];
 coords = Flatten[Table[{-n/2 + k, r - n}, {n, 0, r}, {k, 0, n}], 1];

 Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> coords,
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({Black, 
      Inset[Framed[Style[#2 /. e -> elem, 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
        Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 3], #1]} &)]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That is what I was trying to do before I gave up and asked the question.  I've added it to my .nb

Answer (score 3):

For $r \in \{2 \ldots 10\}$, you can use `GraphData[{"TriangularGrid", r}]` to get a graph with the desired structure:

```
GraphData["TriangularG*"]
```

> {{"TriangularGrid", 2}, {"TriangularGrid", 3}, {"TriangularGrid", 
>     4}, {"TriangularGrid", 5}, {"TriangularGrid", 6}, {"TriangularGrid",
>      7}, {"TriangularGrid", 8}, {"TriangularGrid", 
>     9}, {"TriangularGrid", 10}}

For example,

```
GraphData[{"TriangularGrid", 4}]
```

[image]

We can use it to make a function to add labels and other options:

```
ClearAll[tF, labelingF, tGG]

tF = Flatten@Table[2^(n - k) 3^k, {n, 0, #}, {k, 0, n}] &;

labelingF = AssociationThread[Range @ Length @ #, #] & @ tF[#] &;

tGG = Module[{tg = GraphData[{"TriangularGrid", #}], lbl = labelingF[#]}, 
    SetProperty[tg,
       {VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[Framed[Style[lbl @ #2, Black], 
          RoundingRadius -> 5, FrameStyle -> Gray, Background -> White], #] &), ##2}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[tGG[#, EdgeStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {3, 5, 7}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]